# how to access SQLAlchemy to Django Model?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy

A basic Django model looks something like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

The equivalent SQLAlchemy model with declarative base looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class Person(Base):`enter code here`
     __tablename__ = 'persons'
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     first_name = Column(String(30))
     last_name = Column(String(30))
```

Comment: What is your question? I see only statements.

Comment: i goning to use ORM SQLAlchemy you see above code define Class in and create table in SQLA but in Django Model deffrent , i going to access of models of django model in SQLA , how ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but it looks like you want to access Django models from SQLAlchemy and vice versa? You can either add a function to each class that returns its opposite version (sort of pointless), *or* you can create models of each variety that map to the same database (not pointless, but only useful in special circumstances (same DB backing two projects)). Both are pretty annoying, and *all* ORMs do some pretty boneheaded things in the db on non-trivial schemas. I would recommend writing your own store/retrieve functions in psycopg2, actually.

Comment: Yes ! i going access Django models from SQLAlchemy? how? i can create table on SQLAchemy also i have Django model this means i have two table , i need access fields django model in SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a function to each class that returns its opposite version, or you can create models of each variety that map to the same database. The having each class be able to return its opposite version is pretty much pointless. Having two ORM frameworks map to the same database is only useful if you have a *very* simple data schema (otherwise the mapping gets very difficult from whichever framework did not create the database).

Both are pretty annoying, and all ORMs do some pretty boneheaded things in the db on non-trivial schemas. I would recommend writing your own store/retrieve functions in psycopg2, actually.

I went over some of how to do this from the Django side [here](http://zxq9.com/archives/616). The same sort of thing can be done in SQLAlchemy. What you will quickly find, though, is that you will wind up writing more raw() queries than ORM-based ones -- to the point that it is *actually easier* to just write classes the way *you* want and write serialization methods that use psycopg2 directly to talk to Postgres (or whatever the backend db happens to be -- I'm assuming Postgres because its the most common).

If you already have a database that one of the frameworks created I would *strongly* recommend just sticking with that ORM *or* converting the schema to a for-real relational schema you design by hand. If you had a project that was once a Django web project but now is non-web, you can still use the Django ORM independently of the rest of the framework instead of trying to switch to SQLAlchemy. Once you let an ORM create a schema your project is married to that framework for the rest of its life.

Comment: i don't understand? how integration between SQLA and Django Model?

Comment: @RaminFarajpourCami There is *no* direct translation from SQLA models to Django models. You will have to write the conversion by hand, either by mapping SQLA objects to Django objects, or by writing your own database read/write methods on each SQLA model. That is a ton of work for no benefit.

Comment: i need work project django with SQLAlchemy without Django model , do you have idea for this ?